# Camera position cause objects to disappear

Tags: asp.net-core, three.js, blazor-client-side

I'm developing an app with blazor client-side and I need to render a 3D scene.
I have an issue and I guess it is material-related.

I have a composition of parallelepipeds where one of them is fully opaque and the others are transparent.

Depending on the camera angle, the transparent ones completely disappear:

Example where everything is visible:

[image: Example where everything is visible]

Example with 2 missing:

[image: Example with 2 missing]

Example with all missing:

[image: Example with all missing]

Code for transparent parallelepipeds

```js
var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(item.xDimension * _scene.normalizer, item.yDimension * _scene.normalizer, item.zDimension * _scene.normalizer);

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();

var box = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

box.material.color = new THREE.Color("gray");
box.material.opacity = 0.8;
box.material.transparent = true;
```

Code for the camera:

```js
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, width / height, 0.1, 100);
camera.position.set(1.3, 1.3, 1.3);
camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
```

I'm using OrbitControls and every object size is between 0 an 1 (_scene.normalizer is for that purpose)

Do you know why this is happening?

Edit:
I found it being a material depth function issue. Do you know which should I use?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Transparency is tricky with WebGL because a transparent object writes to the depthmap, and then the renderer assumes that subsequent objects behind it are occluded so it skips drawing them. You could avoid this by playing with the material's `.depthTest` and `.depthWrite` attributes ([see the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/Material.depthTest)):

```
box.material.color = new THREE.Color("gray");
box.material.opacity = 0.8;
box.material.transparent = true;
box.material.depthWrite = false;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. The behavior does not change by setting only `depthWrite = false`. When I try also `depthTest = false`the transparent objects cover the opaque one in front of them... It looks like that the transparent stuff is rendered after the opaque. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, transparent objects [are rendered after opaque ones](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/Material.transparent). Have you tried `write = false, test = true` ? If that doesn't work, maybe you can make the opaque objects transparent, but with `opacity = 1`. Can you put up a working example? It's hard to imagine what your scene is doing inside my head and at this point my suggestions are all speculative.

Comment: You're smart! I didn't though of making the opaque objects transparent. That works if I set both depthWrite and depthTest to false.